# Thread and Blocks Concept

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

I am getting started with CUDA and not clear how the blocks and threads concept work. I am getting a little confused sometimes when it is mostly 2-Dimensional and up. If I look into any code that involves blockIdx.x/y or threadIdx.x/y not sure if I am deducing things right.

Any pointers/example that would easily demonstrate this or help me to understand this concept will be helpful.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You haven't asked a question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend taking these 2 webinars:

> GPU Computing using CUDA C – An Introduction (2010)
>   An introduction to the basics of GPU computing using CUDA C. Concepts will be illustrated with walkthroughs of code samples. No prior GPU Computing experience required

and

> GPU Computing using CUDA C – Advanced 1 (2010)
>   First level optimization techniques such as global memory optimization, and processor utilization. Concepts will be illustrated using real code examples

from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-computing-webinars)

It would be 2 hours well spent.